# What are some planes (spaces) akin to the trace-determinant plane in other disciplines?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions

When studying basic differential equations, I found the [trace-determinant plane](https://elmer.unibas.ch/pendulum/2dflows.gif) incredibly illuminating. Similarly, I find it very helpful to see different kinds of conics as [slices of a cone](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Conic_Sections.svg). What are some examples of similar spaces that generalize classes of behavior or entity to slices of a well-chosen space?